# Evaluate $\int \frac{2\pi y}{2y^3-1}\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate:

> $$\int \dfrac{2\pi y}{2y^3-1}\,dy$$

I've been struggling with this for a while. If it had just been $y^3$ instead of $2y^3$ in the Denominator, Partial Fraction Decomposition, although quite long, would be one method of evaluating the Integral. However, I just cannot understand what to do with this Integral.$$$$I would be indeed very grateful for any help in solving this Integral. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition still works. You might, however, first do a simple change of variables, from $y$ to $2^{-1/3} y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use partial fraction decomposition.  Express

$$\frac{x}{x^3-1} = \frac{A x+B}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{C}{x-1} $$

where $x=2^{1/3} y$.  Note that

$$x^2+x+1 = \left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac34$$

$$A x+B = A \left ( x+\frac12 \right ) + B - \frac12 A$$

$$\int \frac{dx}{\left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac34} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan{\left (\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right )}$$

$$\int dx \frac{x+\frac12}{\left ( x+\frac12 \right )^2+\frac34} = \frac12 \log{(x^2+x+1)}$$

Comment: Thanks Sir. Sir, I converted the Integral into $$\dfrac{16\pi}{2^{1/3}}\int\dfrac{x}{x^3-1} dx$$ But after that, I couldn't understand what you asked me to note. Could you please elaborate a bit, Sir?

Comment: Sir, I wrote $$\dfrac{x}{x^3-1} = \dfrac{1}{3}\bigg(\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+x+1}\bigg)$$

Comment: @BetterWorld: see additions to answer.

Comment: Sir, I still couldn't understand. Sir, I wrote $$\int\dfrac{x}{x^3-1}dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\bigg(\ln(x-1)-\int\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+x+1}dx \bigg )$$
I then wrote $$x-1= A\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^2+x+1)+B$$ and took $A=\dfrac{1}{2}, B=\dfrac{-3}{2}.$ Finally, I completed the square in the Denominator to get $$\int\dfrac{x-1}{x^2+x+1}dx =\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\bigg(\dfrac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg) $$